# How to remote SSH connect to my Raspberry Pi with static local IP?

Tags: ssh, ip, port, raspberry-pi, nat

I am trying to make my Rasperry Pi remotely accesable. The problem that I am stuck with is that while remotely trying to SSH connect to my device I cannot login due to false credentials:

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 pi@111.22.333.444
```

I guess I am trying to connect to the wrong device? I tried to setup my router to forward all **Port 22** accesses to the **local ip** of my raspberry. I can also locally connect to the raspberry:

```
ssh pi@192.168.1.100
```

To achieve this I tried to set up a **NAT virtual server** with a **PVC0** interface:

```
Rule 0, Startport 22, Endport 22, Local IP Address: 192.168.1.100
```

What am I missing? How can I debug this problem?

P.S. I also checked with [Open Ports](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) that my Port 22 is open!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research the problem was that you cannot connect from an external IP through SSH while being a local member of the network.

I now connected to the Internet with the tethering help of my mobile phone and everything works just fine.